# Google Fit Session title not "sticking"

Tags: android, google-fit

My Referee watch creates a Google Fit Session using the following code:

```
        private void insertFitSession(final Game currentGame, final Period period,
                                  final long periodStartTime, final long periodEndTime) {
        //add the detailed Sensor data (using History API) if available
        boolean activityWasInserted = false;
        if (!RefWatchUtil.isRefWatchFree()) {
            //If there are speeds then we will insert an activity
            //4.5.09: Unfortunately mFitnessDataSets[] can have leftover data from a period where you did track fitness
            //So we had to replace with period-by-period dataSets
            activityWasInserted = (period.getFitnessDataSet(SPEED_LISTENER_IDX) != null)
                                    && !period.getFitnessDataSet(SPEED_LISTENER_IDX).isEmpty();
        }

        //create a Session in Google Fit for the period that just completed
        //(this happens even for Free)
        try {

            String sessionBaseName =  currentGame.getTitle();
            if (sessionBaseName.isEmpty()) sessionBaseName = currentGame.getLocation();
            if (sessionBaseName.isEmpty()) sessionBaseName = RefWatchUtil.timeMillisToDefaultShortDateTime(currentGame.getStartTimeMillis());

            final String sessionName = sessionBaseName +  ": " + String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.fitness_period_label), period.getPeriodNum());

            final Session.Builder fitnessSessionBuilder = new Session.Builder();
            fitnessSessionBuilder
                    .setName(sessionName)
                    .setIdentifier(sessionName)
                    .setDescription(mCurrentGame.getDescription())
                    .setStartTime(periodStartTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setEndTime(periodEndTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            //If we're Free, then we don't have real fitness session data and just guess at Jogging
            // (also if we have no Activity data in Pro)
            if (RefWatchUtil.isRefWatchFree() || !activityWasInserted) {
                fitnessSessionBuilder.setActivity(FitnessActivities.RUNNING_JOGGING);
            }
            final Session fitSession = fitnessSessionBuilder.build();

            SessionInsertRequest insertRequest = new SessionInsertRequest.Builder()
                    .setSession(fitSession)
                    .build();

            Fitness.SessionsApi.insertSession(mFitnessApiClient, insertRequest)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully inserted Session " + sessionName);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the session " + sessionName
                                        + ": " + status.getStatusCode() + " " + status.getStatusMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });

        } catch (RuntimeException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "There was a runtime exception inserting the session: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
```

Note the sessionName defaults to either Title, Location, or Time appended with the current Period. This has been working great.

Recently (last month or so?) the Fit session is correctly inserted (I can track it in the log) but the Name doesn't stick. Instead I get "25 min running" for some, but not all, of them.

Has anybody else experienced this type of override by Fit?